# Connection between eigenvalues and P.S.D.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A$ and $B$ be a matrix (symmetric if necessary). Further denote the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ as $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ resprectively.
I would like to know if the following is equivalent:
$\alpha_i\leq\beta_i$ for all $i$ $\iff$ $B-A$ is positiv semi definite.

If not, is there any other correlation to the eigenvalues of A and B?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are ordered, i.e., $\alpha_1\leq\alpha_2\leq\cdots$ and similarly for $\beta_i$, then the answer is yes: it’s a corollary of [Weyl’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_about_perturbation), specifically when $R\geq 0$. (Without such ordering the result is false.)

Comment: Thank you very much.  With this inequality i see why $B-A$ is p.s.d. under the assumption of the eigenvalues but does the other direction also hold?

Comment: @riodemarie Actually, if $B-A$ is p.s.d., then the inequalities follow. The converse implication does **not** hold.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices.

As a consequence of [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_about_perturbation), it holds that if $B - A$ is positive semidefinite, then $\alpha_i \leq \beta_i$ for all $i$. However, the converse inequality does not hold.

For example, consider the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\ 1 & 1}.
$$
It is true that $\alpha_i \leq \beta_i$ for $i = 1,2$ since we have $\alpha_2 = \beta_2 = 0,$ $\alpha_1 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 2$. However, the matrix $B- A$ is not positive semidefinite since it has a negative determinant.